# Average and standard deviation methods returning as NaN

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm making a program that gets the averages and standard deviation of the numbers that are imputed in an array. I'm stuck on only one thing though: whenever the average and standard deviation are returned, it shows up as Not a Number. What is wrong with the code?

Here's the methods:

```
    public mainFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

private double avg;
private double stdDeviation;
private double[] gradeArray;

    /**
     *
     * @param gradeArray
     * @param numElem
     * @return
     */
    public double getAverage (double[] gradeArray, int numElem) {
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<numElem;i++){
        sum = sum + gradeArray[i];
    }
    return (sum/numElem);        
}

public double getStdDev (double[] gradeArray, int numElem, double avg){
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<numElem;i++){
        sum = sum + Math.pow((gradeArray[i]-avg),2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(sum/numElem);
```

And here is the event code when the "Enter Grades" button is clicked on:

```
final int SIZE = 25;
double[] gradeArray = new double[SIZE];
String s;
int numElem = 0;
double average = 0;

for(int i=0;i<=SIZE;i++){

    s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Grade","");
    if (s == null || s == ("")){
        break;

    }
    else{
        try{
            gradeArray[i] = Double.parseDouble (s);
            average = getAverage(gradeArray,numElem);
            stdDeviation = getStdDev(gradeArray,numElem,avg);
            txtGradeEntered.setText(1 + i + "");
            txtMean.setText(average +"");
            txtStdDev.setText(stdDeviation+"");

        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your input must be numeric!","Bad  Data!",0);
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You can only input 25 values!","Too much data!",0);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: `numElem` starts at 0. In `getAverage` you therefore divide by 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with division with such statement: `return (sum/numElem);` where `numElm` is initialized as`0` and `sum` is also `0` because the following never gets executed:

```
for(int i=0;i<numElem;i++){ //<---- numElem = 0
        sum = sum + gradeArray[i];
    }
```

A `NaN` value is used to represent the result of certain invalid operations such as dividing
zero  by  zero.  NaN  constants  of  both float  and double  type  are  predefined  as
`Float.NaN` and `Double.NaN`.

So initialize or set this `numElem` to some other value.